# GPS data storage system

Tags: python, mysql, linux, scripting, twisted

I have a python script written using twisted module which is running on an ubuntu server as a service.
We have many gps devices which sends data every 10 sec. My job is to parse that data and store it in database.
Everything is working fine, but total number of concurrent connections is somehow limited to 1012 on my server. I don't know if it is servers fault or my script.
Plz enlighten me, Is running python script as a service a good practice?or it should run by some other means and why my connections are limited to the wired number 1012.

python script:-

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

class Message:
    """Parse message and save it in database"""

class Echo(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        factory_obj.c += 1

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        try:
            msg = data.decode('utf-8')
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            pass
        else:
            message_handler.handle_message(msg)
            self.transport.write(data)

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        factory_obj.c -= 1


class EchoFactory(Factory):
    def __init__(self):
        self.c = 0

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return Echo()


class Db:
    """handles database"""


factory_obj = EchoFactory()
message_handler = Message()
database_obj = Db()
a = TCP4ServerEndpoint(reactor, 4995, interface='0.0.0.0', backlog=100000)
a.listen(factory_obj)
reactor.run()
```

I think my script is correct, there is some problem with server configuration, although I have tried many things like playing with ulimits and all, nothing worked.
Help me on this please.

Thanks!!

Comment: So, what exactly happens if you try to create a 1013th connection?

Comment: What is the ulimit for maximum number of file handles set to?

Comment: @KlausD. , it doesn't allow any other device to connect. Lets say now connected devices are 1012, when a device is disconnected it starts accepting connections again

Comment: @NickODell , ulimit -n gives 1024

Comment: @PriyanshKhandelwal Every socket counts as a filehandle. Add in a few file handles for opening your source code, some libraries, etc, and you have 1024 file handles.

Comment: @NickODell what do you suggest, the value of file handlers ?

Comment: @PriyanshKhandelwal Enough to support enough connections to your service? I have no idea what "enough" means for your particular case.

Comment: @NickODell even after changing file handlers to 10k, connections are limited to 1012

Comment: @PriyanshKhandelwal "connections (still) limited". Did you restart the machine that program is running on? Very likely that is at the kernel level and the easiest solution to get all file handles is to reboot. Good luck!

Comment: @shellter still limited, even after restarting.

Comment: did you confirm that `ulimit -n` shows the correct number of file handles? If yes, then sorry, I'm out of ideas. Seems like it must be a limit to Python or one of the libraries you're using. (oh, hmm, you're not importing any (networking) libraries /-;?) . True Python experts will have to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got an answer!! As I am running this python script as service, I just had to write LimitNOFILE=50000 under service section. Check service file below for more clarification.

```
[Unit]
  Description=Name of your file
  After=network.target
[Service]
  Type=simple
  User=name of the user
  ExecStart=command to run the script
  Restart=always
  LimitNOFILE=60000
[Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and through this we can even achieve more than 65535 connections. We just have to specify LimitNOFILE value (make sure your server can handle that)

Answer (score 0):

Increase `max_connections` to more than the number of devices you have.

Some Operating systems set ulimit to 1o24 for each process.

```
ulimit -n 4096
```

Or append these two lines to /etc/security/limits.conf

```
mysql hard nofile 65535 
mysql soft nofile 65535
```

Comment: why should we set limit for mysql, does it have something to do with concurrent connections. And also nofile limits is already set to 10k but it didn't help

Comment: `nofile` controls `ulimit`; `ulimit` and the OS feed this to MySQL _during startup_.  Then MySQL sets `max_connections` -- this is the proximate limiter.

Comment: its not working either